# How to bring up Adapter to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, adapter

I am using 3 tabs and each of them have fragments. I need to bring this Activity to Fragment of tab. is this possible?

```
public class MActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}
```

}

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, container, false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);


    return rootView;
}
```

Can someone help me edit the fragment class to bring the activity from Adapter.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the right answer from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798943/image-gridview-inside-fragment)

```
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext()));
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One not so clean but the simplest way is to do this:

```
 public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
        activityAdapter = (MActivity)getActivity().getImageAdapter();
        return rootView;
    }
```

expose a adapter getter in your activity->

```
public class MActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        this.adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridView.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    }

    public ImageAdapter getImageAdapter(){
        return this.adapter;
    }
}
```

The second method would be to create a constructor in your fragment, to take in the adapter object when the fragment is constructed. (This would be a much cleaner object)

Comment: I get errors at `activityAdapter = (MAcitivity)getActivity().getImageAdapter();` errors are at `acitivityAdapter` and `getImageAdapter`

Comment: try to force the brackets. it should work - ((MActivity)getActivity()).getImageAdapter()

Comment: still `activityAdapter` error is not fixed and now i get red underline from the open of 1st bracket to `getActivity())` as the error says `cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity' to com.example.app.MActivity`

Comment: okay.. then i would suggest you to follow the other answer.. using the constructor approach

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your problem is correct, one way is to pass the activity/context object through constructors of your ViewPager Adapter and Fragments.

Comment: Im looking for the corrected codes too for the fragment.

Comment: Hi.. what he is saying is that you just need to add a parameterized constructor. I don't think answers require explicit code if it is that obvious

Comment: Fragments need to have no parameter constructor through which they are recreated e.g. on screen rotation. Unless the fragment is retained, you'll lose everything that is not saved via `onSaveInstanceState` mechanism.